# Changing a greek letter control sequence

Tags: greek, letters

I have a TeX document with many occurrences of a Greek letter, say `\kappa`. Is there a command to change all `\kappa`s to another letter, say `\omega` all at once, without changing each `\kappa` to `\omega` manually?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community.

Comment: as the posted answer shows you could easily do his but I'd strongly advise against it. Even if there are a few hundreds, or few thousand `\kappa` in your document, changing them to `\omega` in your editor should only take a few seconds to type the replacement text. If you redefine the command then any fragments of the document that you move later to a new document or any fragmnts you copy from elsewhere won't get errors but will silently produce the wrong symbols. the document will be "an accident waiting to happen"

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as this:

```
\renewcommand{\kappa}{\omega}
```

in the preamble?

The only caveat is that it'll no longer be possible to use `\kappa` for κ, so if you want to map something else to κ, it won't work. If needed, you can use `\let` to “save” the old `\kappa` with a different name. E.g., if you wanted to switch `\omega` and `\kappa` you could do:

```
\let\oldkappa=\kappa
\let\oldomega=\omega
\renewcommand{\kappa}{\oldomega}
\renewcommand{\omega}{\oldkappa}
```

Don't just use renewcommand with both the old names, or you'll at best end up with two commands the same, and at worst with circular definitions and neverending compilation process.

Comment: Great! That works.

Comment: It might be better to issue `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\kappa}{\omega}}` if there are packages loaded that (re)define `\kappa`. Doubt it, but still.